# How to check current time continuously in a django app?

Tags: python, django, datetime, background

As a fresher in django i am trying to make an django app which will take name and date of birth from user and will send a birthday reminder to user.

Now i have setup model for it but i am stuck at how can i check the current date time continuously in background so that we can send reminder to the user.

Below is my sample Model for it.
models.py

```
class BirthDayModel(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=30)
    birthdate=models.DateTimeField()
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1)
    timestamp=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Please suggest on it.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should try cron like service to check periodically in the background.

Other good options are Django celery and [apscheduler](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). And also if you have websocket using Django channels then try [beatserver](https://github.com/rajasimon/beatserver)